# Generate an XML

Tags: php, xml, json, api, centos

I've made a script which can generate XML based on some tables in my Mysql database.
This script is running in PHP.

```
public function getRawMaterials($apiKey, $format = 'json') {
    if($this::checkApiKey($apiKey)) {
        if(!Cache::has($apiKey . '_rawMaterialData')) {
            $companyID = DB::table('apiKeys')
                ->select('companyID')
                ->where('apiKey', $apiKey)
                ->pluck('companyID');

            $rawMaterials = DB::table('rawMaterials')
                ->join('companySupplier', 'companySupplier.supplier', '=', 'rawMaterials.supplierID')
                ->where('companySupplier.company', $companyID)
                ->take(3)
                ->get();

            $nutritions = DB::table('nevoExpl')->select('nutrientcode', 'nederlandse_nutrientnaam', 'meeteenheid_nutrient')->get();
            $allergens = DB::table('allergens')->get();
            $dangers = DB::table('dangers')->get();

            $data = (array)$rawMaterials;

            for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) {

                $data[$i] = (array)$data[$i];

                // Initialize these variables
                $data[$i]['ingredients'] = array();
                $data[$i]['nutritions'] = array();
                $data[$i]['allergens'] = array();
                //$data[$i]['dangers'] = array();

                $ingredients = DB::table('ingredients')
                    ->select('ingredients.*', 'rawMaterialIngredients.weight')
                    ->join('rawMaterialIngredients', 'rawMaterialIngredients.ingredientID', '=', 'ingredients.ingredientID')
                    ->where('rawMaterialIngredients.rawMaterialID', $data[$i]['rawMaterialID'])
                    ->get();

                $data[$i]['ingredients'] = (array)$ingredients;

                for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($data[$i]['ingredients']); $j++) {

                    $data[$i]['ingredients'][$j] = (array)$ingredients[$j];

                    // Check what allergens are in the products
                    foreach($allergens as $allergen) {
                        if(array_key_exists($allergen->allergen, $data[$i])) {
                            if(!array_key_exists($allergen->allergen, $data[$i]['allergens']) && $data[$i][$allergen->allergen] == "M") {
                                $data[$i]['allergens'][$allergen->id] = array(
                                    'allergenID'    => $allergen->id,
                                    'allergenName'  => $allergen->allergen,
                                    'allergenValue' => 'M'
                                );
                            }

                            unset($data[$i][$allergen->allergen]);
                        }

                        if(array_key_exists($allergen->allergen, $data[$i]['ingredients'][$j])) {
                            if(!array_key_exists($allergen->allergen, $data[$i]['allergens']) && $data[$i]['ingredients'][$j][$allergen->allergen] == "M") {
                                $data[$i]['allergens'][$allergen->id] = array(
                                    'allergenID'    => $allergen->id,
                                    'allergenName'  => $allergen->allergen,
                                    'allergenValue' => 'M'
                                );
                            }

                            unset($data[$i]['ingredients'][$j][$allergen->allergen]);
                        }
                    }

                    // foreach($dangers as $danger) {
                        // if(array_key_exists($danger->danger, $data[$i]['ingredients'][$j])) {
                            // if(array_key_exists($danger->danger, $data[$i]['dangers'])) {
                                // $data[$i]['dangers'][$danger->danger] = "M";
                            // }

                            // unset($data[$i]['ingredients'][$j][$danger->danger]);
                        // }
                    // }
                }

                foreach($nutritions as $nutrition) {
                    if(!array_key_exists($nutrition->nutrientcode, $data[$i]['nutritions'])) {
                        $data[$i]['nutritions'][] = array(
                            'nutritionCode'     => $nutrition->nutrientcode,
                            'nutritionName'     => $nutrition->nederlandse_nutrientnaam,
                            'nutritionMeasure'  => $nutrition->meeteenheid_nutrient,
                            'nutritionValue'    => $data[$i][$nutrition->nutrientcode]
                        );
                    }

                    // Don't need this anymore, so let's get rid of it!
                    unset($data[$i][$nutrition->nutrientcode]);
                }
            }

            $data['Generated_on'] = date('d-m-Y G:i:s', time());

            Cache::put($apiKey . '_rawMaterialData', $data, 720);

        }
        else {
            $data = Cache::get($apiKey . '_rawMaterialData');
        }
    }
    else {
        $data['error'] = 'Dit is geen geldige API code.';
    }

    return $this::format($data, $format);
}
```

The problem with using this script is that it runs out of memory when processing alot of data.
We however need to process this much data because we want to make a xml which can be used by our costumers.

Currently we're running this script as a API but we're open for other suggestions (even suggestions that are not related to PHP)
We just want a way to export our products (to a API, FTP or whatever) to a XML (and JSON) file so our clients can use it. We also want it to be lightweight. We also want it to have levels like:

```
<xml>
    <item>
        <rawMaterialID>567</rawMaterialID>
        <rawMaterialName>Gehakt 60 40  HOH</rawMaterialName>
        <rawMaterialSpecDate>2014-10-19 16:17:14</rawMaterialSpecDate>
        <rawMaterialSpecSource>koetsier vleeswaren bv</rawMaterialSpecSource>
        <supplierID>28</supplierID>
        <supplierDescription>gehakt hoh</supplierDescription>
        <articleNumber>60250</articleNumber>
        <supplierArticleNumber>2002733</supplierArticleNumber>
        <barCode>0</barCode>
        <originCountry>1</originCountry>
        <productionCountry>1</productionCountry>
        <id>1</id>
        <company>15</company>
        <supplier>28</supplier>
        <ingredients>
            <ingredient>
                <ingredientID>226</ingredientID>
                <ingredientName>varkensvlees</ingredientName>
                <ingredientNameIMIS>varkensvlees</ingredientNameIMIS>
                <enumber/>
                <enumberAddition/>
                <general_comments/>
                <further_info/>
                <albaList>Varkensvlees</albaList>
                <adi/>
                <aeromonas>Z</aeromonas>
                <baccereus>Z</baccereus>
                <campylobact>Z</campylobact>
                <clostbot>Z</clostbot>
                <clost_Perf>Z</clost_Perf>
                <e_coli>Z</e_coli>
                <e_coli_O157H7>Z</e_coli_O157H7>
                <listeria>Z</listeria>
                <salmonella>Z</salmonella>
                <shigella>Z</shigella>
                <staph_Aur>Z</staph_Aur>
                <staph_coag>Z</staph_coag>
                <yersinia>Z</yersinia>
                <vibrio_col>Z</vibrio_col>
                <vibrio_para>Z</vibrio_para>
                <vibrio_vuln>Z</vibrio_vuln>
                <mycobacteria>Z</mycobacteria>
                <brucella>Z</brucella>
                <aflatoxin>Z</aflatoxin>
                <patuline>Z</patuline>
                <echratoxin>Z</echratoxin>
                <fusarium>Z</fusarium>
                <ergot>Z</ergot>
                <fumonisin>Z</fumonisin>
                <rubratoxin>Z</rubratoxin>
                <zearalenone>Z</zearalenone>
                <hepatitis>Z</hepatitis>
                <viral_gastroenteritis>Z</viral_gastroenteritis>
                <polio>Z</polio>
                <rickets>Z</rickets>
                <prions>Z</prions>
                <moulds_yeast>Z</moulds_yeast>
                <anisakis_marina>Z</anisakis_marina>
                <cryptosporidium_parvum>Z</cryptosporidium_parvum>
                <echinococcus_granulosis>Z</echinococcus_granulosis>
                <entamoeba_histolytica>Z</entamoeba_histolytica>
                <giardia_lamblia>Z</giardia_lamblia>
                <fasciola_hepatica>Z</fasciola_hepatica>
                <clonorchis_sinensis>Z</clonorchis_sinensis>
                <taenia_saginata>Z</taenia_saginata>
                <taenia_solium>Z</taenia_solium>
                <toxoplasma_gondii>Z</toxoplasma_gondii>
                <trichinella_spiralis>Z</trichinella_spiralis>
                <meelmijt_Tyroglyphus_farinae_L>Z</meelmijt_Tyroglyphus_farinae_L>
                <flies>Z</flies>
                <ants>Z</ants>
                <mites>Z</mites>
                <beetles>Z</beetles>
                <cockroaches>Z</cockroaches>
                <moths>Z</moths>
                <rodents>Z</rodents>
                <weevils>Z</weevils>
                <bone_fragments>Z</bone_fragments>
                <stones>Z</stones>
                <insect_fragments>Z</insect_fragments>
                <choke>Z</choke>
                <metal_fragments>Z</metal_fragments>
                <glass>Z</glass>
                <createdBy/>
                <dateCreated>2014-07-02 14:38:22</dateCreated>
                <changedBy/>
                <dateChanged/>
                <weight>600</weight>
            </ingredient>
            <ingredient>
                <ingredientID>200</ingredientID>
                <ingredientName>rundvlees</ingredientName>
                <ingredientNameIMIS>rundvlees</ingredientNameIMIS>
                <enumber/>
                <enumberAddition/>
                <general_comments/>
                <further_info/>
                <albaList>Rundvlees</albaList>
                <adi/>
                <aeromonas>Z</aeromonas>
                <baccereus>Z</baccereus>
                <campylobact>Z</campylobact>
                <clostbot>Z</clostbot>
                <clost_Perf>Z</clost_Perf>
                <e_coli>Z</e_coli>
                <e_coli_O157H7>Z</e_coli_O157H7>
                <listeria>Z</listeria>
                <salmonella>Z</salmonella>
                <shigella>Z</shigella>
                <staph_Aur>Z</staph_Aur>
                <staph_coag>Z</staph_coag>
                <yersinia>Z</yersinia>
                <vibrio_col>Z</vibrio_col>
                <vibrio_para>Z</vibrio_para>
                <vibrio_vuln>Z</vibrio_vuln>
                <mycobacteria>Z</mycobacteria>
                <brucella>Z</brucella>
                <aflatoxin>Z</aflatoxin>
                <patuline>Z</patuline>
                <echratoxin>Z</echratoxin>
                <fusarium>Z</fusarium>
                <ergot>Z</ergot>
                <fumonisin>Z</fumonisin>
                <rubratoxin>Z</rubratoxin>
                <zearalenone>Z</zearalenone>
                <hepatitis>Z</hepatitis>
                <viral_gastroenteritis>Z</viral_gastroenteritis>
                <polio>Z</polio>
                <rickets>Z</rickets>
                <prions>Z</prions>
                <moulds_yeast>Z</moulds_yeast>
                <anisakis_marina>Z</anisakis_marina>
                <cryptosporidium_parvum>Z</cryptosporidium_parvum>
                <echinococcus_granulosis>Z</echinococcus_granulosis>
                <entamoeba_histolytica>Z</entamoeba_histolytica>
                <giardia_lamblia>Z</giardia_lamblia>
                <fasciola_hepatica>Z</fasciola_hepatica>
                <clonorchis_sinensis>Z</clonorchis_sinensis>
                <taenia_saginata>Z</taenia_saginata>
                <taenia_solium>Z</taenia_solium>
                <toxoplasma_gondii>Z</toxoplasma_gondii>
                <trichinella_spiralis>Z</trichinella_spiralis>
                <meelmijt_Tyroglyphus_farinae_L>Z</meelmijt_Tyroglyphus_farinae_L>
                <flies>Z</flies>
                <ants>Z</ants>
                <mites>Z</mites>
                <beetles>Z</beetles>
                <cockroaches>Z</cockroaches>
                <moths>Z</moths>
                <rodents>Z</rodents>
                <weevils>Z</weevils>
                <bone_fragments>Z</bone_fragments>
                <stones>Z</stones>
                <insect_fragments>Z</insect_fragments>
                <choke>Z</choke>
                <metal_fragments>Z</metal_fragments>
                <glass>Z</glass>
                <createdBy/>
                <dateCreated>2014-07-02 14:38:22</dateCreated>
                <changedBy/>
                <dateChanged/>
                <weight>400</weight>
            </ingredient>
        </ingredients>
        <nutritions>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_01001</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Energie</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>kcal</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>233</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_01002</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Energie</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>kJ</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>969</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_02001</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Stikstof totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>3.1</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_02002</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Eiwit totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>19.2</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_02003</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Eiwit plantaardig</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_02004</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Eiwit dierlijk</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>19.2</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_03001</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vet totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>17.2</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_03002</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Som van de vetzuren</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>16.2</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_03004</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vetzuren totaal verzadigd</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>6.9</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_03006</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vetzuren enkelv onverz cis</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>7.5</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_03008</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vetzuren meerv onverz</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>1.3</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_03009</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Linolzuur (C18:2(n-6)cis)</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>1.1</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_03136</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vetzuren totaal trans</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_04001</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Cholesterol</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>28.8</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05001</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Koolhydraten totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0.3</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05002</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Suiker Totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0.3</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05003</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Glucose</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05005</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Fructose</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05006</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Lactose</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05008</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Maltose</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05009</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Saccharose</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05010</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Polysacchariden totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05011</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Polyolen totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05012</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Lactitol</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05013</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Xylitol</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05014</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Sorbitol</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_05015</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Isomalt</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_06001</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Voedingsvezel totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0.3</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_07001</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Water</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>63.7</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_08001</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Alcohol totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_09001</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Calcium</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>9</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_09002</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Fosfor</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>169</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_09003</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>IJzer totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>1.3</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_09006</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Natrium</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0.177</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_09007</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Kalium</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>303</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_09008</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Magnesium</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>19</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_09009</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Zink</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>3.22</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_10001</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Selenium</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_10002</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Koper</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_10003</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Jodium</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11001</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Retinol</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11002</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Retinol equivalenten</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11003</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Beta-caroteen</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11005</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vitamine B1</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11006</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vitamine B2</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11007</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vitamine B6 totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11008</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vitamine B12</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11009</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vitamine D totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11010</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vitamine E totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11011</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vitamine C</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11013</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Foliumzuur</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11014</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Nicotinezuur</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>mg</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11020</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Alfa-caroteen</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11022</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Zeaxanthine</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11024</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Lycopeen</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11035</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vitamine K totaal</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11036</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vitamine K1</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11038</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Vitamine K2</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>ug</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11039</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Zout</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11040</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Omega 3 vetzuren N-3</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
            <nutrition>
                <nutritionCode>n_11041</nutritionCode>
                <nutritionName>Omega 6 vetzuren N-6</nutritionName>
                <nutritionMeasure>g</nutritionMeasure>
                <nutritionValue>0</nutritionValue>
            </nutrition>
        </nutritions>
        <allergens>
            <allergen>
                <allergenID>14</allergenID>
                <allergenName>rundvlees</allergenName>
                <allergenValue>M</allergenValue>
            </allergen>
            <allergen>
                <allergenID>15</allergenID>
                <allergenName>varkensvlees</allergenName>
                <allergenValue>M</allergenValue>
            </allergen>
        </allergens>
    </item>
</xml>
```

I hope somebody can help us.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you're building a massive data structure and then outputting that in a particular format.  If you have memory issues, the normal way to get round this is to split it into smaller structures and output them piecemeal.  This is similar to how some XML readers work (using callbacks).  It'll be a non-trivial switch over, but if you want to reduce memory usage it initially seems like the only option.

Comment: Basic idea - decompose your structure and write something that will output a single entity - call that in your loop, discarding the data structure as you go along.  That said, you might have trouble with your DB library as it looks like you get everything in one go from there.  You'd be better with a callback per record returned, or the ability to loop over the result set as it is being returned rather than once you've got it all out of the DB.

Comment: Yes I've also been thinking of making centos run this script like every hour 50 records at a time via a cronjob. But isn't there like a official way to handle this kind of stuff?

Comment: "official"?  You mean as in officially sanctioned by the PHP Governing Body?  ;-)  I know what you mean, and yes, I'd say the "official" way of doing it would be to write something that can be easily decomposed and discards the resources as it uses them.  That would be either by using callbacks, or a `->next` style loop / iterator

Comment: Could you write a little example of your suggestion @Rob Baillie

Comment: Sorry, it's beyond my time constraints right now, but if I get a chance later...

Comment: Ye sure whenever you have time on hand, It's not really on top of our priority list at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

When is the error thrown ? What amount of data ?

if the out of memory error occur during format operation, maybe you could split your big json or xml in multiple files then concatenate them.

But the real thing you should do in any case is page your output with a maximum output of n-entities by page if you database contains 1 million records, it is not surprising your php complains about memory...

If you don't do that, your clients will get the same problem, lack of memory when thay'll try to parse your datas...

Comment: It depends on what client wants to export the data, I'd say it's about 2000 records or more. So you're saying I should split the job into multiple files and then concatenate them? And how much entities would be a good point to split?

Comment: Could you give me a little example of that?

Comment: It's hard to give you an example without writing the whole code for you. But in order to avoid memory issue, you limit the amount of data you are iterating over with a `LIMIT N OFFSET X` in your SQL (paging datas), do the job n-times (n stands for "necessary" :) ). And then you use a file stream to output your datas line by line to limit the footprint of your program. Personnaly I would create an object that keep the state of the last xml tags that are opened to do this part.

Comment: So basically write a function that processes 50 records and then calls the function again for the next 50 records using recursion?

Comment: you can do it this way, but IMHO,the important part is the way you output your XML (Actually, it depends on when the memory issue occurs).

Comment: And what if I make a separate xml file for every n amount of records. That will also prevent having trouble importing the xml

Comment: yes that's why I was previously talking about "paging your output", if you are in an api, your clients will make a GET request on `api/myrequest/page/1 ` but if you want to corectly output your xml and your memory management to be bullet-proof, you shouldn't keep the output in memory (here a veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery long string)  but append it to a file line by line, even if you are making pages. because you cannot neither predict how many ingredients there will be nor "nutrition" item.

Comment: I might write it to file and move it to a ftp location so the client gets his content from there.

Comment: maybe you could export this as an sql file or a sqlite database (single .db file) with a little script to display the data, it would be easier to handle for your client and for you

Comment: It has to be in xml though :(